# What does the run() method do in a Task Runnable object?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement multithreading using tasks. My end goal is to loop through a bunch of numbers and check if they're prime, like so:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                primes.add(i);
            }
        }
```

I was to use threads to check each iteration independently to speed up the process. I have a separate class that adds threads to a work queue, and accepts tasks to be added to the queue for threads to work on.

The part I'm tripping up on is the Task portion, which I currently have implemented as an inner class in my driver class:

```
private class Task implements Runnable {
    /** The path to add or list. */
    private final int number;

    /** The amount of pending (or unfinished) work. */
    private int pending;

    /**
     * Initializes this task.
     *
     * @param b the path to add or list
     */
    public Task(int number) {
        this.number = number;
        incrementPending();
        System.out.println("Task for {} created." + number);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Task for {} finished." + number);
        decrementPending();
    }

    /**
     * Safely increments the shared pending variable.
     */
    private synchronized void incrementPending() {
        pending++;
    }

    /**
     * Safely decrements the shared pending variable, and wakes up any threads
     * waiting for work to be completed.
     */
    private synchronized void decrementPending() {
        assert pending > 0;
        pending--;

        if (pending == 0) {
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to implement the run() method. Should I put isPrime in there? Do I need to create new Tasks with a parameter isPrime? What goes in the run() portion, and how do I create and use the Task objects?

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming! I would suggest looking at the basics of Multi Threading and how to run sth on Multi Threaded environment. That way you will get the fundamentals clear and easily solve the homework problems like this

Comment: I have been looking through this stuff for hours and it doesn't make sense to me... that's why I'm asking this specific question here

Comment: So your first step was re-inventing `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but without a clue how to use it? And the second step was to create that inner class whose main purpose seems to be maintaining a useless `pending` variable? You can turn your loop into a parallel operation using `List<Integer> primes = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, max) .parallel() .filter(i -> isPrime(i)) .boxed() .collect(Collectors.toList());`